# Initializing a variable after a a raise or an exceptiom in Try Except Raise

Tags: python, try-catch

in python

If can we use initialize a variable after a raise keyword. For example

```
 Try:    
   func(x)  
 except ValueError  
 raise  
 data = {}
```

or

```
Try:    
   func(x)  
except Exception 
data = {}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens? Try it you why not do see happens what.

Comment: First of all you should fix the code so that it is valid Python

Answer (score 0):

It exits the program with the raised argument:

**Tried code:**

```
try:
    print(3+2)
finally:
    print('Goodby World!')
raise KeyboardInterrupt 
print(343)
```

**Output:**

```
5
Goodby World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lists.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```